# VirtualStringTree with a Default TButton

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

I have a form with a VirtualStringTree (VST) and a TButton with its default property set to `true`. The nodes of the VST contain inplace editors (TEdits). The problem is that the button always fires when editing the VST. How can I keep the button as default but have it ignore the <kbd>enter</kbd> key when the VST is being edited?

Comment: Maybe you could clear the `Default` property when editing begins and set it again when editing is complete. I'm pretty sure the tree control has events that let you detect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rob says you may use VirtualTree events to temporary disable `Button.Default` property.
For example :

In **OnEditing** event disable Default property

```
Button.Default := false;
```

In  **OnEdited** and **OnEditCancelled** events restore Default property

```
Button.Default := true;
```

Comment: I can't see an issue here. The default node editor properly eats the key, so there's no need to do anything.

Comment: @TLama I don't agree with you. I simulated the problem in Delphi. Button with default property captures key before node editor. The above solution works and it is tested.

Comment: Still cannot reproduce. I just dropped a button with enabled `Default` property with a click handler showing a message, VT (6.1.0) where I included `toEditable` into the `TreeOptions.MiscOptions` and added a few nodes. When I ran such application (built in Delphi XE3), started to edit a node and pressed Enter key. no message was shown. Hence I cannot see any problem.

Comment: @TLama, I also can't reproduce (Version 4.5.5)

Comment: @TLama this happens when own edit link `TEdit` is implemented. Delphi 2010, VT 5.5.3

Comment: Well, implement it like `TVTEdit` then.

Comment: @TLama what about if `TComboBox` is implemented for example(or other).

Comment: This solution solves my problem since I am not using standard tbuttons. However, it is worth noting that this solution would have a slight issue when using Tbuttons because the default button would lose its highlighting when editing the VST.